# CiviMail - Bounces with "Failed to set sender"

Tags: bounce

Emails in CiviMail are bouncing with the following error message:

> Failed to set sender: b.17.13.b9ecea4c55fed5e3@example.com [SMTP:
> Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email.
> This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings.
> Please verify the settings at Admi

Outbound email settings are good and test emails sent from there work.

Taking a cue from [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7270/civimail-smtp-error-when-sending-test-email), I looked at "Administer - CiviMail - Mail Accounts."

When using IMAP there, I get the following error:

> An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to
> the server: my.example.com:143. (See log for more details.)

The log is as follows:

```
Apr 14 06:41:17  [warning] MailSettings: Failed to establish test connection
Array
(
    [exception] => ezcMailTransportException: "An error occured while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the server: my.example.com:143."
#0 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/transports/imap/imap_transport.php(403): ezcMailTransportConnection->__construct()
#1 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/MailStore/Imap.php(58): ezcMailImapTransport->__construct()
#2 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/MailStore.php(76): CRM_Mailing_MailStore_Imap->__construct()
#3 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/MailStore.php(53): CRM_Mailing_MailStore::{closure}()
#4 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Action/MailSettings/TestConnection.php(28): CRM_Mailing_MailStore::getStore()
#5 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/BasicBatchAction.php(92): Civi\Api4\Action\MailSettings\TestConnection->doTask()
#6 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/BasicBatchAction.php(75): Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicBatchAction->processBatch()
#7 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(72): Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicBatchAction->_run()
#8 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(158): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke()
#9 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(250): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest()
#10 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(85): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#11 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/MailSettings.php(214): civicrm_api4()
#12 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(573): CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings->postProcess()
#13 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(152): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#14 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(119): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform()
#15 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform()
#16 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
#17 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
#18 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(334): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#19 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(140): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit()
#20 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(319): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#21 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#22 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#23 /app/data/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#24 /app/code/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#25 /app/code/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#26 /app/code/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#27 /app/code/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#28 {main}

)
```

(This is not surprising as my server uses a different port for IMAP, but I'm not sure where to change that in CiviCRM.)

However, the connection succeeds when the Maildir protocol is selected.

I'm not sure if "Administer - CiviMail - Mail Accounts" has anything to do with the bounces in CiviMail, but any help regarding next steps is appreciated.

Using CiviCRM 5.57.0 with Wordpress 6.2.

Comment: There is definitely an issue with your inbound server setup. Whether that is also preventing sending is hard for me to say, but it is conceivable. I can't find docs on setting a custom port, but I would try adding it via a colon at the end of the server line like this: `mail.server.com:1234`

Comment: Thank you. Adding the port did change the error message which now reads: "An error occured while sending or receiving mail. The connection to the IMAP server is ok, but a negative response from server was received. Try again later. (See log for more details.)"

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I needed to enable masquerading on my server which "allows users and apps to send emails with an arbitrary username in the FROM address."

I am now able to send through CiviMail.

I thought of this as the tail end of the error message was:

> (code: 550, response: Authenticated user user@example.com cannot send mail as b.17.14.5c9e67488c7c2078@example.com)